# How to imitate the functionality of ZEROIFNULL in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Teradata has a function called `ZEROIFNULL`, which does what the name suggests, if the value of a column is NULL, it returns zero. On similar lines, there's a function called NULLIFZERO as well.

I want to imitate/mock these functionalities in SparkSQL(not using the dataframe or RDD APIs, instead, I want to use them in SparkSQL, where you directly pass the SQLs.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```py
sqlContext.sql("select COALESCE(column,0)")
```

Returns zero if column is `NULL`.

To mimic NULLIFZERO, you could use `case when`

```
select case when col=0 then NULL end from tbl
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Any trick for NULLIFZERO as well, please? :)

Comment: NVL works too :) . For NULLIFZERO, write `case - when - then - else` ?

Comment: I am not sure if NVL works, will have to try. But you could use `case when` like this `select case when col=0 then NULL end from tbl`

Comment: Alternatively you could try `nullif(a,b)`

Comment: Great! Thank you!

I'll accept this as answer. Can you please include for NULLIFZERO part in your answer, as well?